# How to add a suffix to all items in a column?

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

I've tried concatenation, but the list has 120K records and it crashes.

Any idea on how can I solve this please?

Comment: You really need to give more details on how you've been trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to use a regex in Find and replace dialog.

First select your column cells, than open the dialog and check `Regular expressions` in `More Options`, than  search for:

```
^(.+)$
```

Replace with:

```
&YOUR_SUFFIX
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that has the concatenation for one cell in it, then fill the column for all the rows needed for the 120K records.  Then copy the values of the column onto itself and delete the original column.

Comment: I've tried that, but it only goes halfway up to 60K records, then just stops and the cell remains blank, it then crashes if I try to do anything. I have free disk space, ssd disk, and an intel i7 pc with like 16gb ram..... I dont get this, source file is a simple .csv.....

Comment: Ok, then load the file, delete half the lines, then do that.  Repeat for 2nd half. then recombine each half.